# Custom TableViewController sounds play and crash in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, avplayer

I am working with an Array of audio in Swift 3.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class TableViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var players: [AVAudioPlayer] = []
    var audioFileNames = [String?]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        audioFileNames = [ "ɔɪ", "eə", "aʊ", "eɪ"]
    }
```

I have the individual sounds appear in a custom cell. If I press one cell the sound plays but when I press another cell the app freezes and crashes.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.audioFileNames.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.audioFileNames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

The code breaks here at this function.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        players = [setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: self.audioFileNames[indexPath.row]! as String,  type: "mp3")!]
        players[indexPath.row].play()
    }

    func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: String, type: String) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file as String, ofType: type as String)
        let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)

        var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        } catch {
            print("Player not available")
        }

        return audioPlayer
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } 
}
```

Comment: The problem is `players = [setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: self.audioFileNames[indexPath.row]! as String,  type: "mp3")!]`.

Comment: you dont need to create audioplayer array use only one audio player and just stop and start once you click on tableview cell

Answer (score 0):

1. you must initialize `players` in `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   players = Array(repeating: nil, count: audioFileNames.count)
   ```
2. you must check player initiated before you use it

   ```
   if players[indexPath.row] == nil {
       players[indexPath.row] = setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: self.audioFileNames[indexPath.row]! as String,  type: "mp3")    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it doesn't work with array of players. You need to play them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure it's some kind of buggy behavior of swift
i found that if you init like this:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer? = nil
```

it will be better; and every time you refer to it, add a "`?`" to it
for example:

```
player?.play()
```

it will stop crashing when the URL is not set. 
There are cases where this is really necessary and there's no other obvious alternatives.

If anyone finds a better solution, please let me know!